# Can I send Action Notifications to non-Foundry users?

Tags: gmail, palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I want to use Action Notifications to send emails to an array of email addresses. Some of these email addresses belong to non-Foundry users. So far I have not been able to find a way to do this. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only send Notifications using Foundry user or group IDs. Sending notifications directly to email addresses is not possible. However, you can configure forwarding/redirecting rules in most major email providers like [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en#zippy=%2Conly-forward-certain-kinds-of-messages) or [Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-rules-in-outlook-web-app-to-automatically-forward-messages-to-another-account-1433e3a0-7fb0-4999-b536-50e05cb67fed#:%7E:text=Under%20When%20the%20message%20arrives,Save%20to%20create%20the%20rule.). Just set up a function-backed action with notifications and configure notifications to include data that will fit into the logic of whatever routing rule you configured in your email. (Screenshot below from [documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/notifications/)).
[image]